# Laravel 8 not finding "tag" from package "\Conner\Tagging\Taggable;"

Tags: php, laravel, tags, laravel-8

The code works perfectly when I want to create a new tag from scratch, but when `$skillsQuery->count() > 0` and enters in the if statement. It prints...

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tag does not exist.

How can I update tags using this package?

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function storeSkills(Request $request)
{
    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    $skillsQuery = Skill::where('created_by', $id)->get();

    // If skill exists
    if ($skillsQuery->count() > 0) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $tags = explode(", ", $input['name']);
        // $skill = Skill::create($input);
        $skillsQuery->tag($tags);
        $skillsQuery->created_by = $id;

        if ($skillsQuery->save()) {
            return redirect()->route('profile')->with('success', 'Skills updated successfully');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('profile')->with('error', 'Error updated your Skills!');
        }
    } else {
        $input = $request->all();
        $tags = explode(", ", $input['name']);
        $skill = Skill::create($input);
        $skill->tag($tags);
        $skill->created_by = $id;

        if ($skill->save())
            return redirect()->route('profile')->with('success', 'Skills stored successfully');
        else {
            return redirect()->route('profile')->with('error', 'Error storing your Skills!');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of calling `->get()` on a `Illuminate\Database\Query` is that you will receive an instance of a `Illuminate\Database\Collection`, which does not contain a `->tag()` method. Even if it was a query (by removing `->get()`) this still would not work, as you can't call a relationship method off of a collection.

If instead you loop over the `skillsQuery` then you will receive an instance of a `Model` object which then allows you to access functions and/or relationships off of it:

```
$skillsQuery->each(function ($skill) use ($tags) {
  $skill->tag($tags); // or perhaps ->retag($tags); here
});
```